# Unable to load c++ dll, even VB.Net exe and .dll in same folder

Tags: c++, .net, vb.net, dll, production-environment

I have application in VB.Net and unmanaged dll. When I run application in my PC it works fine. But when  I try to run it in production it gives, 'unable to load dll' error.

In my pc, I have kept .exe and .dll by creating different folder than my actual release folder and it works fine.

My pc is 64 bit machine and production environment is 32 bit.

I have tried all combination like, 'Any Cpu', 'x86', 'Win32', noting seems to work on production machine.

Exe and dll are in same folder, so no need to (I think) worry about path, it is not COM dll, so no need to register (and it is native c++ dll).

I have gone through many questions, used dependency walker as well, still facing problem.

We are using Visual Studio 2012.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the DLL have dependancies on other DLLs that you are not putting on your test machine, and might be in the GAC on your machine?

Comment: @Steve It has dependency on other dlls, but will it cause fail loading dll?

Comment: I dont know if it depends on what the DLL does and where it does it (more than likely if it references the DLL in the init somewhere or some shared/staic memebers) but sometimes it does, and sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved problem myself. It was VC++ 12 runtime not installed on production machine.